# Z-Buffer rendering issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm working on a rendering project in which I need stereoscopic frames rendering along with depth (in both openexr and normalized png formats).

I need the depth inverted in respect to the blender original format, so I need white for near objects and black for far objects. 
I did this with compositing, implementing a node tree that inverts the depth output and does some elaboration in order to normalize the values between a far plane and a near plane defined by me. 
I need this cause, as you know, by default the z-buffer uses the camera clipping planes as far and near planes, but I need to use a narrower range between the planes in respect to the range of the camera, and I cannot do this by modifying the camera clipping planes as this would end in clipped objects in the final render.

Now, I animated my camera and rendered the frames but I encountered some issues. When I tried to render on the CPU some of the depth PNG files resulted completely black (actually, they are white at the output of the render layer but black in the file, since I invert the depth as explained above). Same for the openexr files, for which I have some really light files (few KBytes) while the rest are around 1MB.

Then I tried to render on the GPU. In this case there are no black depth files, but I have an even more weird behavior: some of the files seem to be normalized in a different way than the rest (the distance from the camera to the objects in the view doesn't change as the camera only mover horizontally along X axis).
Here are 2 consecutive frames to show you the problem:
[image: Frame 1]

[image: Frame 2]

Here is an explained screenshot of my compositing node tree

[image]

To do the new range normalization, I basically create a mask indicating the pixels that are in the new range (expressed in millimeters) using the greater than/less than nodes and combining them with a multiply node. Then I multiply the mask with the inverted non-normalized depth (lets call RANGEDEPTH the output of this multiplication). After this, I do different operations to get the PNG and the openxer outputs.
For the PNG, I multiply the normalized mask and the normalized RANGEDEPTH.
For the openexr, I multiply the normalized mask and the non-normalized RANGEDEPTH.
I know it is a bit tricky but when I implemented this and tested on a single frame it worked well.

EDIT: in the very moment I finished writing this, I think I understood the reason of the problem with the different normalization. 
As you probably understood, the subject of the render is a filled supermarket shelf, and behind it there is just a wall around 5 meters far away. 
Looking at all the depth images among the 100 frames I rendered, I noticed that the brighter depth images are the ones in which the wall is visible, while in the darker ones the wall is not visible as the shelf completely obfuscates it. My conclusion is that the "normalize" nodes used in the node tree normalize the depth looking at the maximum and minimum values in the buffer and not looking at the camera clipping planes as I thought.
Is there any node with which I can normalize in respect to the camera clipping planes?
I still have no clue why there are some completely black depth files when rendering on the CPU though.

EDIT 2: doing some research, I found out that the node "Map range" node does exactly what I need without all that complicated node tree. I still have no explanation for the black frames on the CPU.